# How do I turn off a usb device completely by terminal?

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, lsusb

My ThinkPad T480 running Linux has a fingerprint scanner that shows up to `lsusb` as

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc.
```

There are no drivers for this fingerprint scanner, and according to PowerTop, it is constantly checking and using up battery.

How do I turn it off completely?

Comment: Are you able to disable it in the firmware settings?

Comment: @Spaceguy99.  There is an option in the T480 firmware configuration to disable the fingerprint scanner.